# How to add a percentage uploader when uploading a file using {{uploader}}

Tags: meteor

Am using the {{uploader}} in my code and whenever the user uploads an image, it shows him ("uploading + fileName...")

this is the code for it

```
let upload = ( options ) => {
  template = options.template;
  let file = _getFileFromInput( options.event );
  let config = options.config;

  _setPlaceholderText( `Uploading ${file.name}...` );
  _uploadFileToAmazon( file, config );
};
```

the problem is when the user chooses a big size file he will be waiting for quite sometime, so its better to have an uploading percentage instead of ("loading...")

am using meteor add edgee:slingshot package for uploading to Amazon S3

this is the code where am calling the uploader

```
var uploader
  if (config === '1') {
      uploader = new Slingshot.Upload( "uploadToAmazonS3Cg1" );
  } 
  if (config === '2') {
      uploader = new Slingshot.Upload( "uploadToAmazonS3Cg2" );
  }
  if (config === '3') {
      uploader = new Slingshot.Upload( "uploadToAmazonS3Cg3" );
  }
  var progress = Math.round(uploader.progress() * 100);
```

I tried to create the template helper as show below:

```
Template.uploader.helpers({
    progress: function(uploader){
        var progress = Math.round(uploader.progress() * 100)
        return progress;
    }
});
```

and then i called it inside my helper with `{{progress}}`, it didn't work

how can i accomplish this?

Comment: What kind of uploader are you using?

Comment: @StephenWoods am using meteor add edgee:slingshot package for uploading to Amazon S3

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
var uploader = new Slingshot.Upload("myFileUploads")
// ...get your upload started and save the uploader (in state for React or in a template variable in Blaze)
var progress = Math.round(uploader.progress() * 100)
```

Comment: I edited my question after implementing your solution, where should i put the progress variable in use? because nothing happened with me. still shows me uploading....

Comment: You want to create template helper called {{progress}} where you do this line. `var progress = Math.round(uploader.progress() * 100)`

Comment: sorry i dived-in in Meteor in Javascript and didn't know what you meant by then, now i get the hang of it and get back to your reply and tried to implement your solution, i updated my question if you could help me please